# How can I Connect a Postgres Schema in Nodejs and Switching Schemas Dynamically Using Sequelize?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, schema

I have to connect to a Postgres database in Node.js and I want to switch schemas dynamically Using Sequelize Library.

Here is my Table Model and Controller Code.

```
    module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const customer = sequelize.define(
        'customer',
        {
            id: {
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            },
            schema_name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            created_on: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
                allowNull: false,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW(),
            },
        },
        {
            schema: 'public',
        }
    )
    return customer
}
```

And Controller Code

```
    exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
        const { email, password, domain } = req.body
        const domainData = await customer.findOne({
             where: { schema_name: domain },
        })
        console.log('Log: exports.login -> domainData', domainData)
}
```

Once the response received I have to **Switch Schemas Dynamically** according to the above result.

Help me Guys Please

Comment: You can change the [search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) at runtime

Comment: https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/model/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem using **sequelize.query()** function.

for getting **Domain**...

```
    const domainData = await sequelize.query(
    `SELECT schema_name from public.customer_management_client where schema_name = '${domain}'`
)
```

for switching to **dynamic schema**

```
const UserData = await sequelize.query(
            `SELECT * from ${domainData[0][0].schema_name}.user_access_user where email = '${email}'`
        )
```